# PHP Convert Byte to byte array

Tags: php, arrays, byte, converters

My code receive some json with a byte field like `48656C6C6F`,and I'm trying to convert it to a byte pairs in array like `array[0] = 48, array[1]=65 ...` in order to work with each byte.

Actually, I've made this bypass function in order to have the array:

```
function Array_conv($hex){
    $chunks = str_split($hex, 2);
    $result = implode(',', $chunks);
    return $result;
}
```

The question is, have a right way to convert to a byte array, or to hex like 0x48..

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get `array[1]=34` from your byte field `48656C6C6F`?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yoru code seems to work just fine? I get them as comma-separated values (because you use `implode()`).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that there is actually a PHP function called `array_chunk()` (yours is spelled incorrectly, which is why it works). You may want to consider a different name.

Comment: Consider if the length is not a valid pair of two byte-pairs, what if the string is `F59`, would you then want `0x0F` and `0x59` as a value?

Comment: @Qirel what I'm looking is a way to convert a "string" of bytes, in byte-pairs, in order to make some bitewise after, like grab the first to pairs and apply some math to get a first GPS coordinates numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in PHP are just as well suited  to access every single byte as arrays.

```
$hex = "48656C6C6F";
$string = hex2bin($hex);
var_dump($string);  //string(5) "Hello"
```

The function strlen() returns the length in Byte. With a simple for loop you can get every Byte. With ord() you get the byte as an unsigned integer between 0 and 255.

```
$byteLen = strlen($string);
for($i=0; $i < $byteLen; $i++){
  $byte = $string[$i];
  echo ord($byte).",";
}
```

Output:

```
72,101,108,108,111,
```